# perturbative series expansion of integral via complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Define for real $x>0$ and $\epsilon>0,$ the function
$$ f(x,\epsilon):= \int_{\epsilon}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{s} \frac{1}{\sinh^2 s/2} e^{-sx}. $$

Question: is it possible to compute explicitly $f$ by a residue calculation?

The idea would be to obtain something like
$$f(x)=\sum_g F_g x^{2-2g} + O(e^{-x}).$$

Comment: Your integrand has a triple pole at $s=0$, so the limit won't exit regardless of how large $x$ is. Are you asking for asymptotics in $x$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: OK, and what would be the answer?

Comment: better, one should keep $\epsilon$ small but finite, and look at poles $s=\pi i n.$

Comment: After substituting $x = u + \epsilon$ you can use Watson's lemma to obtain an asymptotic expansion of $f(x,\epsilon)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: $\large{1 \over z\sinh^{2}\left(z\right)} \sim {1 \over z^{3}} - {1 \over 3z}$ when $\large z \sim 0$.